# Cudd: extracting variable ordering

Tags: c++, c, cudd

I'm trying to leverage CUDD's variable ordering heuristics for another program.  I have created a BDD, tried a few variable orderings to see which one minimizes the size, and now I want to extract the variable ordering.  How can I do this?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994614/cudd-package-way-to-pass-a-specific-variable-order), the `dd` python package gives you a way to inspect the level of each variable, but I don't see a corresponding function in the C/C++ interface.  How does that python binding pull it off?  Does it require accessing CUDD internals through `cuddInt.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I should have read the source code of `dd`.  The answer is quite simple: use `Cudd_ReadPerm`.